# Ajax POST sends null Value

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

in the template of my website I try to do an Ajax POST request to send the cordinates of the user to the server, which then should output the corresponding nearest city. However currently the only thing Ajax does is outputing a null value.

The whole project uses the django framework. To make sure that the crsf is not the reason I disabled crsf protection for the whole site. I also tried instead of passing json, strings integers etc, all returned null. Additionally my success function is fireing, so the ajax function is clearly working.

```
<script>
var loc = [] ;



function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    loc.push( "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  loc.push(position.coords.latitude) ; 
  loc.push(position.coords.longitude) ; 
}








</script>
<script >
window.onload = function(){
  getLocation();
};

$.ajax({

  url: '{% url "locnews" %}', 
  type : "post",
  data:  {
    "location": loc 
  },
  datatype : "json",
  success : console.log("succ"),

})





</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition)
aren't you calling showPosition without passing "position" parameter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The functions purpose is to show the users longitude and latitude cordinates, so no parameters are required

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the problem out myself. Apparently AJAX was fireing before getLocation() was finished. The issue got resolved once I added the Ajax call into the getLocation() function.